# Where the probe() function's argument comes from?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm studying linux device driver. currently, I understand flows of device driver approximatively, but I dont know how probe() function gets its arguments.

For example, here is my code and this is based on kernel 3.10.

```
static int gpio_led_probe(struct platform_device *pdev) {
       struct gpio_led_platform_data *pdata = pdev->dev.platform_data;
       struct gpio_leds_priv *priv;
       ....
       priv = gpio_leds_create_of(pdev);
       ....
}
```

As like this, the argument 'pdev' is using for various point of source. I'm understading when probe() called and it's role, but I cannot find where the data 'pdev' comes from.

thanks for read my thread, and sorry that my english is not good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

platform device specific data while probing comes from the platform setup code or from **device tree**.
you can find the related code in **arch/arm/borad/device** files
**struct platform_device** embedded with **platform_data structure** where you will pass the platform related data to the drivers.

in modern kernels platform data is passed to device drivers through device tree. device tree can be found in **/arch/arm/boot/dts/your_device**

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the platform device information by filling the platform_device structure or you have to provide your device information in device tree, during system bootup, platform_device structure gets populated based on the device tree information.In latest kernel usually we use device tree to get the device information.